# setcookie только для index.php

Tags: php, cookie

Как указать в `setcookie`, что куки должны быть видны только с одной страницы сайта, если эта страница index.php?

```
setcookie("Name", values, time()+60*60*24*31,
"/index.php", "subdomain.domain.org", TRUE, TRUE);
```

Всё отлично работает, если обращаться к странице `subdomain.domain.org/index.php`. А если просто `subdomain.domain.org`, разумеется, нет. Что можно придумать, кроме перенаправления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.4), установить куку для `/` так, чтобы она не соответствовала, скажем `/foo` - НЕЛЬЗЯ.

Потому, что:

> Путь у текущего запроса (request_path) соответствует заданному cookie-path если хотя-бы одно из следуюших условий выполняется:
>
> - cookie-path и request_path - идентичны.
> - cookie-path является префиксом для request_path и последний символ у cookie-path - %x2F ("/").
> - cookie-path является префиксом для request_path и первый символ у
>   request-path, который не встречается в cookie-path является %x2F ("/") символом.